# How to read multiple files from a folder, combine the data in a single file, and add a variable with names of original files?

Tags: r, python-3.x

I have a folder with 80 log files and their names are years they were created (example `2008P1.log`, `2008P2.log`, `2009P1.log`, etc.). Each file has a single column of data with more than 100000 rows. I want to put all these data in a single file in a sequence of their name(year wise).

The sequence would be the year they were created, oldest first, latest last.

Also I need an additional column in new file with the name of the file they were taken from.

I need to do this with Python or R.

Files:

```
2008
2008P1
2008p2
2009P1
2009p3
.
.
.
.
.
2019P3
```

Data in file:

```
$h|fffff|P|....
$C|fffff|P|....
.
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: You say each file has a single column and then post data like `$h|fffff|P|`. Care to explain a bit better? Is this several columns separated by bars `|`? And the dollar sign at the beginning, does it have a special meaning? Are the file names like you posted or do they have an `.txt` extension?

Comment: This is the data we have. No meaning to the data as of now..I just need all this data to be moved into a new single file. But also want to keep the knowledge of where this data was taken from, so want to add another column with file name as text.

$H¦N¦4B92¦R.I¦U¦48396270¦0¦C8¦0
$H¦N¦4B93¦R.I¦U¦48396271¦0¦C8¦0
$H¦N¦4B94¦R.I¦U¦48396272¦0¦C8¦0
$H¦N¦4B95¦R.I¦U¦48396273¦0¦C8¦0
$H¦N¦4B96¦R.I¦U¦48396274¦0¦C8¦0

files are in .log extension but they will open with text editors or excel.

Answer (score 0):

I echo @RuiBarradas's comment that it is not easy to understand what your log files look like.

Since you mention a column, I imagine that the separators are line breaks. I also made the assumption that those columns don't have headers. If either of these assumptions is false, you will have to play with the arguments of `read.table()` or use `read.delim()` instead.

Here is a suggestion:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# Make a list of your files
files <- list.files(path = "/your/folder/path", pattern = "\\d{4}[Pp]?\\d?\\.log")

# Create a function to read a file and create your new variable
read_file_and_create_col <- function(file) {
  read.table(file, stringsAsFactors = F) %>% 
    mutate(name = sub(".*/(.*)\\.log", "\\1", file))
}

# Apply it to each file and output to a data frame
map_df(files, read_file_and_create_col)
```

The ordering should be as you want it by default. If, for some reason, it were not, you can order your new file by adding `%>% arrange(name)` to the last line of code.

Answer (score 0):

In base R the following could be what you want. Tested with 3 files with names and data like you have posted.

```
filenames <- list.files(pattern = "^[[:digit:]]{4}.*\\.log$")
filenames <- filenames[order(toupper(filenames))]
df_list <- lapply(filenames, read.table)
df_list <- lapply(seq_along(filenames), function(i){
  df_list[[i]]$file <- filenames[i]
  df_list[[i]]
})

outfile <- "outfile.txt"
write.table(df_list[[1]], outfile, quote = FALSE, 
            row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
lapply(df_list[-1], function(DF){
  write.table(DF, outfile, 
              append = TRUE, quote = FALSE, 
              row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
})
```